# Datensatz aller deutschen "Basis"-Nomen

Tags: noun

Es gibt im Netz einige Datensätze der deutschen Worte und auch speziell der Nomen zu finden, die z.B. aus Zeitungsartikeln gesammelt wurden.

Leider finden sich darunter sehr viele zusammengesetzte Nomen wie
"Autobahnraststätte".

**Gibt es eine Regel/einen Datensatz wie ich aus diesen Nomen die in ihrer Bedeutung nicht trennbaren Nomen herausfiltern kann (Auto,Bahn,Rast,Stätte), aus denen
alle anderen zusammengesetzt sind?**

Ich gehe davon aus, dass es kaum eine allgemeine Regel geben kann aber kann man eine approximieren?
Für den Datensatz würden mich auch proprietäre Lösungen interessieren.

PS: Auch Softwarelösungen sind interessant, allerdings scheinen da die meisten äußerst unpräzise zu sein.

Comment: Raststätte ist zusammengesetzt aus "Rast" und "Stätte".

Comment: *Urinstinkt* ist zusammengesetzt aus ...

Answer (score 1):

Wiktionary listet sehr viele deutsche Nomen auf. Die Kategorie [German nouns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:German_nouns) listet verschiedene Unterkategorien auf. Sofern hier keine Fehler enthalten sind (was natürlich in keiner Quelle auszuschließen ist), lassen sich alle Nomen parsen und man kann anschließend die Differenz mit allen Mengen bilden, die man nicht haben möchte (sprich die z.B. in den Listen [compound terms](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:German_compound_terms) oder [proper nouns](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Category:German_proper_nouns) auftauchen.)